# Reverse Proxy using Apache directives

Tags: module, reverse-proxy, apache, proxypass

I am trying to do reverse proxy using Apache directives

I will get a url like this: https://192.168.1.67:/fes-bin/public/ezidentity/js/jquery-1.2.6.js

I want to modify it like: https://192.168.1.70:9843/portal/ezidentity/js/jquery-1.2.6.js

now part of my configuration file is like this ::

```
ProxyPass /home/fes/public/ezidentity/ https://192.168.1.70:9843/portal/ezidentity/

ProxyPassReverse /home/fes/public/ezidentity/ https://192.168.1.70:9843/portal/ezidentity/
```

and above i have written Alias /fes-bin/ "/home/fes/" thats why i have used "/home/fes/" in Pass* directives.

this is not getting worked . The page still says content not found , however if i access it directly through browser file gets loaded .

i am using Apache version above 2.0 .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example URL, it looks like the directives should be the following.

```
ProxyPass /fes-bin/public/ https://192.168.1.70:9843/portal/
ProxyPassReverse /fes-bin/public/ https://192.168.1.70:9843/portal/
```

**Edit** I have just recently been "playing" with Apache as a reverse proxy, so I am by no means knowledgeable about it.  I did, however, get it working very easily.  In addition to the ProxyPass directives, I also specified a `Listen 8080` directive and specified that port in the client request.  It may be worth trying that.

Comment: @ Mark thanks for help .I also tried with your changes , it didn't worked. I mean issue is that apache is not even firing any request to backend server , as i have seen from httpanalyzer

Comment: also let me know if any other directive needed for this thing done .

Comment: @Sandeep: You may try specifying the listen directive.  I edited the answer and added that.